# Using angularjs with newer versions

Tags: angularjs

The following code does not seem to work for me. I'm doing the official video tutorial from their website.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>

     <script>
        function TodoCtrl($scope){
            $scope.totalTodos = 4;
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        {{totalTodos}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried to do this tutorial here (http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html) and it does not work with 1.2.12 but when I changed it to 1.0.7 it did.
Am I doing something silly here or are these tutorials too old now?

Comment: I forgot to add that all I see is {{totalTodos}}

Comment: Yeah, you're correct, I copied the it directly from the Google CDN page. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: I chose to answer, since my comment did happen to address the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an Angular version issue.  [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPaw5J?p=preview) that is working with 1.2.12.

I think you are just missiong `http:` at the front of your source.  The tutorial you reference looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

So, your code should reference angular like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
```